# multiple files upload in fckeditor

Tags: c#, fckeditor

how can i have the functionality in fckeditor to have multiple files upload in fckeditor

i want to select multiple files thru its image button in toolbar

Answer (score 0):

You would have to roll your own file upload, not that difficult. Are you using **FCK** editor or **CK** editor. Also which file upload component are you using?

Comment: its fckeditor with jquery plugin
downloaded from 
http://www.fyneworks.com/jquery/FCKEditor/

Comment: Yes, you will have to write your own.

Answer (score 0):

file manager for ckeditor 
http://www.mixedwaves.com/2010/02/integrating-fckeditor-filemanager-in-ckeditor
it's compataible by this editor ,it's FREE,but one file upload by browse.
jquery file upload http://blueimp.github.com/jQuery-File-Upload/
can multi file upload by one browse file.it's free too.